# "Like" button not working, (iframe) version

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I know this is a common question but I haven't found any answers. I click the button but nothing happens. I've been using the linter and have all the og tags.

Here's my code (straight from the like button creator) and site:

```
    <iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=450&amp;show_faces=true&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=21" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

http://alexcieminski.com/index.html

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`?href&` This is the problem.  You need to really put your url-encoded url here: `?href=%3A%2F%2F&`

Also check out your page in the linter:  http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Falexcieminski.com%2Findex.html

It says you should also specify the og:description too.

Comment: Thanks DMCS!  Can you please explain the ?href& in more detail? I'm amateur here and didn't quite understand that.
Thank you.

Comment: The href is the URL you want to be liked.  The easiest thing for you to do is to go back to the Facebook Like plugin page and regenerate the code for building the iframe code (ensuring you have the url specified so it can add it in)

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove all the 'amp;' that separate the query strings. So, instead of having '&' separating each query strings you should just have '&'. You also don't have anything for url for 'href'

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this problem from last 4 hours & it turned out to be a browser related issue. After I've started accepting third party cookies from http://www.facebook.com/ suddenly every thing started working...